# Check Solidworks is installed?

Tags: c#, solidworks

I have a c# application that runs on both 32-bit and 64-bit OS.In my app, how can I programatically check that solidworks is installed or not on computer.If we can check it by reading registry key ,then provide me path for both 32-bit and 64-bit.Tell me if there are other ways also to check it.

Answer (score 5):

You could use WMI as follows

```
private static bool IsInstalled(string ProductName)
{

    bool rv = false;
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
    ManagementObjectCollection Products = searcher.Get();
    if (Products.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject product in Products)
        {
            if (product.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString() == ProductName)
            {
                rv = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return rv;           
}
```

Comment: I would throw 'using' statements around the ManagementObjectSearcher and ManagementObjectCollection to make sure they are disposed of properly.

Comment: You can break the `foreach` loop when product is founded by replacing `rv = true` by `return true` (`rv` declaration becomes unnecessary)

Answer (score 2):

Does the application need to start SolidWorks if it's installed?  If so, I start all my Stand-alone (non add-in) SolidWorks tools with

```
Public swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks

Function GetSolidWorks(ForceLaunch As Boolean) As Boolean
    If Not swApp Is Nothing Then
        SetSolidWorksVisibility()
        Return True
    Else
        Try
            swApp = GetObject(, "SldWorks.Application")
            If swApp Is Nothing Then Return False

            SetSolidWorksVisibility()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            If Not ForceLaunch Then Return False

            swApp = CreateObject("SldWorks.Application")
            If swApp Is Nothing Then Return False

            SetSolidWorksVisibility()

            'simple timer to wait for solidworks to repond
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

            Return True
        End Try
    End If
End Function

Private Sub SetSolidWorksVisibility()
    If Not swApp.Visible Then swApp.Visible = True
    If Not swApp.FrameState = SwConst.swWindowState_e.swWindowMaximized Then swApp.FrameState = SwConst.swWindowState_e.swWindowMaximized
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for beginers....
I think there are many ways to check Whether Solidworks is installed or not , 
but according to my perspective when Solidworks is installed it creates some folders in registery.
Just follow this steps to check it...

> Open **run**  
>  Type **regedit** in that and press
>   **Enter**
>  Allow  'User access control' by clicking on
>   **Yes**
>  Go under  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> **SOFTWARE**

Now check there Is **`Solidwork`** folder entry is available or not 
If folder found solidworks installed otherwise not..!

hope this will help !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what would be required for the macOS versions of Solidworks, but for Windows this should be a reliable way to check if Solidworks is installed.

I suspect this will work with any edition 2010 and beyond as the Solidworks API Help documentation starts there. I have tested with 2018 and beyond.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

/// <summary>
/// Checks that Solidworks has the minimum required version installed 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="requiredVersion ">The minimum year of Solidworks required</param>
/// <exception cref="PlatformNotSupportedException"></exception>
public static bool CheckSolidworks(int requiredVersion = 2_021)
{
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
    {
        var keyname = "SolidWorks";
        var registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey($"SOFTWARE\\{keyname}")
            ?? Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey($"Software\\{keyname}");

        if (registryKey == null)
            return false;

        var matches = registryKey.GetSubKeyNames()?.Where(x => x.StartsWith("SOLIDWORKS"));

        if (matches == null)
            return false;

        int? installedVersion = null;

        foreach (var match in matches)
            if (int.TryParse(match[^4..], out int version) && (installedVersion == null || version > installedVersion))
                installedVersion = version;

        return installedVersion != null && installedVersion >= requiredVersion;
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Method only supported on Windows");
    }
}
```